# Quicksort implementation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I have tried to implement Quicksort and it's not working properly.

Please tell me where I went wrong. Have I implemented the logic incorrectly?
I tested the above code with these set of numbers - 13,26,12,15,10,15,12

```
public class QuickSort {

    private int array[];
    private int arrayLength;

    public void sort(int[] values) {

        if (values == null || values.length == 0)
            return;

        this.array = values;
        this.arrayLength = array.length - 1;

        quickSort(0, arrayLength);
    }

    private void quickSort(int low, int high) {
        int i = low, j = high;

            // Maximum Number of elements should be equal to arraylength
            int leftSubArray[] = new int[high+1];
            int rightSubArray[] = new int[high+1];

            int pivot = array[low];
            System.out.println("Pivot = " + pivot + " and position = " + low);

            int tempMax = low;

            // Divide the list in two parts

            // Left sublist smaller than pivot
            // Incremented by one to exclude the pivot
            while (i < high) {
                if (array[i + 1] < pivot) {
                    leftSubArray[tempMax] = array[i + 1];
                    tempMax++;
                }
                i++;
            }

            // Right sublist greater than pivot
            tempMax = j;
            while (j > low) {
                if (array[j] >= pivot) {
                    rightSubArray[tempMax] = array[j];
                    tempMax--;
                }
                j--;
            }

            // Combining both the arrays
            i = low;
            while (i <= tempMax) {
                array[i] = leftSubArray[i];
                i++;
            }

            array[tempMax] = pivot;

            // defining the limit of the next recursive call
            j = tempMax-1;
            i = low;

            tempMax++;
            while (tempMax <= high) {
                array[tempMax] = rightSubArray[tempMax];
                tempMax++;
            }

            displayArray();

            // Recursion
            if (low < j) 
                quickSort(low, j);

            tempMax++;
            if (tempMax < arrayLength)
                quickSort(tempMax, arrayLength);

    }

    private void displayArray() {
        for (int i : array) {
            System.out.print(i + ",");
        }
        System.out.println("\b\n");
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the console o/p from Eclipse:

```
Pivot = 13 and position = 0
12,10,12,13,26,15,15,

Pivot = 12 and position = 0
10,12,12,13,26,15,15,

Pivot = 26 and position = 4
10,12,12,13,15,15,26,

Pivot = 15 and position = 4
10,12,12,13,15,15,26,

Pivot = 15 and position = 4
10,12,12,13,15,15,0,

Pivot = 10 and position = 0
10,0,0,13,15,15,0,

Pivot = 15 and position = 4
10,0,0,13,0,15,15,

Pivot = 0 and position = 4
10,0,0,13,0,0,0,

Pivot = 10 and position = 0
0,0,10,0,0,0,0,

Pivot = 0 and position = 0
0,0,10,0,0,0,0,

Pivot = 0 and position = 3
0,0,10,0,0,0,0,

Pivot = 0 and position = 0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

Comment: What was the result of your test?

Comment: "It's not working properly" is not an adequate description of any problem. Does it crash? Produce incorrect results? What *exactly* is wrong?

Comment: Woah that's quite a lot of code for quicksort, and very unusual (no partition function?). And why don't you do it in place? That's the main advantage of it. You might be introducing a lot of bugs just because of how you are implementing it.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta By partitioning you mean choosing pivot?

Comment: It's very odd that you have that outer loop there.  The basic quick sort algorithm goes: partition, recurse, recurse. I'd suggest you get that working before making things more complicated.

Comment: If you don't know what "partition" means in the context of quicksort, there is something you are missing. You should refresh on a textbook.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta : here is the logic which I tried to implement : 1)Chosen first element as pivot 2)compare it with the whole list 3)kept element smaller than pivot in leftSubArray and greater or equal to pivot in rightSubArray 4)merging the arrays keeping pivot in middle and the pivot is sorted.Left sub array is smaller than pivot and right sub araay is greater.

Comment: @abc "partitioning" refers to partitioning the array around the pivot. This is an operation typically pushed in a separate function that gets called recursively as TheodoreNorvell pointed out. You should not need to create new arrays as partition is usually implemented in place.

Comment: [This page](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/) has a great description with diagrams.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta Thanks...will definitely go thought the post and will try to implement the same .You may post this as answer if you want.Thanks and sorry once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the guidance from [Giovanni Botta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327788/giovanni-botta)'s [link](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/)  and [Theodore Norvell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667690/theodore-norvell)'s comment I am able to implement the logic corectly.

Answer (score 1):

The below is the working code.

```
public class QuickSort{

int arr[] = {12,9,4,99,120,1,3,130,13};


public static void main(String args[])
{

QuickSort qs = new QuickSort();

qs.quickSort(qs.arr,0,qs.arr.length-1);
System.out.println("");


}

void quickSort(int arr[],int left,int right)
{
   int i = left, j = right;

   int tmp;int p;

   int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];


System.out.println("");

for(p=0;p<arr.length;p++)
{
    System.out.print(arr[p] + " ");

}System.out.println("\n\nPivot = " +pivot+" Left= "+left+" j= " +j+ " I= "+i+ " Right= "+right+"  {before entering do-while}\n");

/* partition */

  while (i <= j) {

        while (arr[i] < pivot)

              i++;

        while (arr[j] > pivot)

              j--;

        if (i <= j) {

              tmp = arr[i];

              arr[i] = arr[j];

              arr[j] = tmp;

              i++;

              j--;

        }
/*for(p=0;p<arr.length;p++)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[p]+" ");

    }
    System.out.println();*/

  }




for(p=0;p<arr.length;p++)
{
    System.out.print(arr[p]+" ");
}

System.out.println("\n\nPivot = " +pivot+" Left= "+left+" j= " +j+ " I= "+i+ " Right= "+right+" {after each do-while}");

/***********/


 /* recursion */

  if (left < j){
    System.out.println("\nInside First if Left = "+left+ " J = " +j);       

        quickSort(arr, left, j);
}

  if (i < right){
    System.out.println("\nInside Second if i = " +i+ " Right = " +right);
        quickSort(arr, i, right);
}

/*******/
```

}
}

Comment: thanks for you code but I want to rectify the code which I wrote..I know its incorrect and that why is not working properly...but I have upvoted your answer

Comment: @pise This question looks like a homework question. I would avoid giving working solutions in such cases, since it's better to learn by understanding and fixing your own mistakes rather than looking at a solution.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta I would have googled and get the code directly from there but instead I tried to implement it on my own and hence posted the question.STOP judging me!

Comment: @abc I apologize if I seemed judgmental, that was not my intention. Besides, I was responding to pise suggesting to help with the question rather than giving a solution. As you also noticed, you want to fix your code and understand why it's not working, which is absolutely fair and reasonable. I was just trying to make that point in general with "homework like" questions.